# GET custom completed field values via API

Tags: docusignapi

Is it possible to get the values from a completed document that used a template?

I'm looking at the [RESTful API section here](https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/RESTAPIGuide.htm#REST%20API%20References/Get%20Custom%20Document%20Fields%20for%20a%20Template%20Document.htm%3FTocPath%3DREST%2520API%2520References%7C_____119)

We use DocuSign for customers to fill out a Direct Debit form and accompanying address details. I'd like to get these via the API and create a CSV file for submission to our Direct Debit broker. Customer services said no, but don't think they understood the question :-)

Comment: Yes so you wan to get the values of the tabs that you're recipients have filled out, right?  Yes that's possible, I'll post an answer...

Answer (score 1):

The API page that you have linked to is for `Custom Fields` not recipient tabs.  To be very clear, `Custom Fields` are fields at the Envelope level and are used for labeling, tracking, and searching your account envelopes.

Recipient Tabs are the fields that your signers fill out when completing your documents.  They are unique to the various types of Recipients you can add to your transactions (such as `signers`, `inPersonSigners`, `carbonCopy`, etc.)  More on Recipients [here](https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/explore/features).

If you add tabs for your recipients, once the document is complete you can make the **[Get Tab Information for Recipient](https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/RESTAPIGuide.htm#REST%20API%20References/Get%20Tab%20Information%20for%20a%20Recipient.htm)** API call to retrieve the actual values.

Example:

```
GET https://{server}/restapi/{apiVersion}/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/recipients/{recipientId}/tabs
```

Sample Response:

```
    "approveTabs":[{
        <Tab information removed>
    }],
    "textTabs":[{
        <Tab information removed>
    }],
    "signHereTabs":[{
        <Tab information removed>
    }]
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Ergin. I should have RTFM to grok the correct term for this. I presumed they were custom fields as we added them. So that means we can use the API to query completed forms and GET the Tabs content. i.e. their address they entered etc. Excellent!

Comment: Yes absolutely, that's a very common use case.

Comment: I wish we had asked here when we signed up as customer services had no clue :-)